# Implementing trained-model on camera

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just trained my model successfully and I have some checkpoints from the training process. Can you explain to me how to use this data to recognize the objects live with the help of a webcam?

Comment: Deserialize your model and feed every N frame. On mobile you'd rather use [tflite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite) model.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations :)

First of all, you use the model to recognize the objects, the model learned from the data, minor detail.

It really depends on what you are aiming for, as the comment suggest, you should probably provide a bit more information.

The simplest setup would probably be to take an image with your webcam, read the file, pass it to the model and get the predictions. If you want to do it live, you are gonna have the stream from the webcam and then pass the images to the model.

Comment: I understand. I have a model with my checkpoints from training, but I don't know how to use them in order to implement it on camera.

Comment: Well you need to acquire the data from the webcam and provide it to the model same as you did with your training data depending on what tensorflow API you are utilizing